# Получить доступ к подчиненным элементам

Tags: python, selenium

```
list = element.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'list')
```

Подскажите, как получить доступ к data-value?
Через драйвер Селениума двигаюсь к нужным тегам, но div не получается получить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)